# Npm dependency conflict - how to solve it?

Tags: npm, graphql

I am trying to install graphql-iso-date. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE  
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: graphql@16.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^16.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^0.5.0 || ^0.6.0 || ^0.7.0 || ^0.8.0-b || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0" from graphql-iso-date@3.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql-iso-date
npm ERR!   graphql-iso-date@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-11T19_26_53_815Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has occured because the peer dependencies were conflicting for new versions of npm.  the package is not so well maintained.

use --legacy-peer-deps with your command.

exact command would be : `npm install graphql-iso-date --legacy-peer-deps`

use --save flag if you need.

Answer (score 3):

Please be careful to run the `npm install <package>` with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.

Let's check the `peerDependencies` of [`graphql-iso-date@3.6.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-iso-date/v/3.6.1) package.

```
$ npm view graphql-iso-date@3.6.1 peerDependencies
{
  graphql: '^0.5.0 || ^0.6.0 || ^0.7.0 || ^0.8.0-b || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0'
}
```

This means it demands the `graphql` package as its peer dependency with these compatibility versions.

Obviously, the `graphql@16.2.0` version is not on the list. That's why you got the warning.

The safe solution is to downgrade the `graphql` package to the compatibility version.

Let's check the all 14.x versions of `graphql` package:

```
$ npm view graphql@14 version
graphql@14.0.0 '14.0.0'
graphql@14.0.1 '14.0.1'
graphql@14.0.2 '14.0.2'
graphql@14.1.0 '14.1.0'
graphql@14.1.1 '14.1.1'
graphql@14.2.0 '14.2.0'
graphql@14.2.1 '14.2.1'
graphql@14.3.0 '14.3.0'
graphql@14.3.1 '14.3.1'
graphql@14.4.0 '14.4.0'
graphql@14.4.1 '14.4.1'
graphql@14.4.2 '14.4.2'
graphql@14.5.0 '14.5.0'
graphql@14.5.1 '14.5.1'
graphql@14.5.2 '14.5.2'
graphql@14.5.3 '14.5.3'
graphql@14.5.4 '14.5.4'
graphql@14.5.5 '14.5.5'
graphql@14.5.6 '14.5.6'
graphql@14.5.7 '14.5.7'
graphql@14.5.8 '14.5.8'
graphql@14.6.0 '14.6.0'
graphql@14.7.0 '14.7.0'
```

We can use the last version of 14.x, it's compatible with `^14.0.0`. Now let's downgrade the version of `graphql` package and install `graphql-iso-date` package

```
$ npm i graphql@^14.7.0 -S

added 1 package, changed 1 package, and audited 3 packages in 26s

found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm i graphql-iso-date -S

added 1 package, and audited 4 packages in 8s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

List the installed packages:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
peer-deps-issue@ /home/lindu/workspace/peer-deps-issue
├── graphql-iso-date@3.6.1
└── graphql@14.7.0
```

The warning is gone. Further reading [npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)

Answer (score 0):

I tried `--legacy-peer-deps` but nothing worked for me so I tried  Running: `npm i -g npm@next-7` and it worked for me.