# npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, dependencies

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-tesseract-ocr@2.0.3
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to install `react-native-tesseract-ocr`. But I faced the mentioned issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609280/6463558, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76635769/6463558

Answer (score 0):

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

It solved the error in my case

Comment: This accepts _"an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution."_ I wouldn't call it a solution.